# Laravel creating a form select with default value set

Tags: php, forms, laravel

Controller:

```
$employee = Staff::where('staff_id', '=', $id)->where('user_role', '=','Employee')->first();
$emp_loc = $employee->locations()->pivot()->only('loc_id');
$locations_list = Location::lists('address1', 'loc_id'); //get list of locations
```

View:

```
<!--location -->
<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label">Location</label>
<div class="controls">
@if(isset($emp_loc))
{{ Form::select('location', $locations_list, $emp_loc) }}
@else
{{ Form::select('location', $locations_list) }}
@endif
</div>
</div>
```

The third parameter is meant to be the default value for the select box however it always begins at the first value.

Source Code:

```
<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label">Location</label>
<div class="controls">
<select name="location"><option value="1">Bethel</option><option value="2">Brooklyn</option><option value="3">Germantown</option><option value="4">Memphis</option><option value="5">Brooklyn</option></select>        </div>
</div>
```

No default value set?

Comment: What `$emp_loc` contains ? It should contain be the value of the option to be selected, like `1` or `2`.

Comment: are you including ->with('emp_loc', $emp_loc) in your controller before render the View? Can you post the code of your controller please.

Comment: Please show the line in your controller where you create the view, or pass the variables to it - there could be something wrong there.  I'd also suggest that you `var_dump`/`echo` the `$emp_loc` so you can confirm that it is indeed a number, it may be set but `null`.

Comment: 1. $emp_loc contains a single number like '1' or '2' based on the id i did a die and dump and they are all correct.
2. all the values are passed to the view
3. I have done a dd on all variables and I use them in the view and it does not return errors so the variables have passed through successfully.

Comment: There is though the chance that it's comparing a string to an integer, I'd suggest doing a var_dump() on both $emp and $locations_list to make sure the id's are identical.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a database configuration problem.

Go back to the migration file and make sure your foreign keys are set properly. This is what I would do to properly set them:

```
Schema::create('pivot', function(Blueprint $table) {
  $table->increments('id');
  $table->unsignedInteger('loc_id');
  $table->foreign('loc_id')
   ->references('id')->on('location_list');
  .....
}

Schema::create('location_list', function(Blueprint $table) {
  $table->increments('id');
  .....
}
```

Moreover, pay attention that in Firefox the `selected` value is not displayed properly. To fix this, change your drop-down list to (in Blade):

```
Form::select('location', $locations_list, $emp_loc, array('autocomplete'=>'off'))
```

This last part is a weird behavior of Firefox